# Spacemacs: settings of l (or h) to move from the end of the line to the beginning of the next line(or vice versa)

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

In the case of vim it is possible to set it as follows.

```vimrc
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
```

How can I set it for Spacemacs(vim editing style)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a Spacemacs-specific "issue", it comes from the included *evil-mode* Emacs package.

*Short answer:*

`(setq evil-cross-lines t)`

... before `evil-mode` is loaded.

In `.spacemacs`, this can be under `dotspacemacs/user-init`

*Long answer:*

Pressing `Ctrl-h k` followed by `l` or `h` shows you what commands are bound to these keys, and (in recent emacs versions), the keymap in which they are defined. The commands (or rather, motions) are `evil-forward-char` and `evil-backward-char`, respectively. Looking at their definition, in `evil-commands.el`, it can be seen that their movement is restricted to the current line - or not - based on the value of the variable `evil-cross-lines`, which is by default `nil`. And the docstring of this variable confirms it: `"Whether motions may cross newlines"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was realized by setting as follows. 
(setq evil-cross-lines t
      evil-search-module 'evil-search
      evil-ex-search-vim-style-regexp t)
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)